# Align elements with different fonts

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align two buttons with different fonts. I can't use an absolute position as the buttons should be adaptable to any screen size. So something like: height -> 10 % of screen
width of button 1 -> 80%, button 2 -> 20% of screen

```css
.button1 {
  font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, "Segoe UI";
  height: 40vh;
  width: 60%;
  display: inline;
}

.button2 {
  font-family: Arial;
  height: 40vh;
  width: 20%;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<button class="button1">Button 1</button>
<button class="button2">2</button>

<br><br> As you can see button 1 is aligned slightly above button 2. This only happens when the font is not the same. Below is an example where they align correctly.

<br><br>

<button class="button1">Button 1</button>
<button class="button1" style="width:30%">2</button>
```

Comment: I think you can use flexbox for this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap your button in a div and give it class '`button-wrapper`', it as display `flex` which will automatically align like row with auto height. `gap` is used give space between them.

```css
.button1 {
  font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, "Segoe UI";
  height: 40vh;
  width: 60%;
  display: inline;
}

.button2 {
  font-family: Arial;
  height: 40vh;
  width: 20%;
  display: inline;
}
.buttons-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  gap:4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons-wrapper">
  <button class="button1">Button 1</button>
  <button class="button2">2</button>
</div>

<br><br> As you can see button 1 is aligned slightly above button 2. This only happens when the font is not the same. Below is an example where they align correctly.

<br><br>

<div class="buttons-wrapper">
  <button class="button1">Button 1</button>
  <button class="button1" style="width:30%">2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank You! Will this also work if I am aligning any other element instead of buttons? Like divs for e.g.

Comment: Also I am unable to center align this div. How am I to go about doing that?

Comment: yes , it will work, refer this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#aa-align-items